# Does the font affects the height of the TextView?

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview

If I am using a constant DP for the `android:textSize` and a fixed number of `android:lines`, does that mean that **for the same device, the height of my TextView will stay the same, no matter which font is used?** All fonts that I tested on my phone suggest that that is the case, but I am not sure.

In Samsung Galaxy, for example, you can change device font and my whole layout depends on this TextView size and I need to know if something can go wrong.

Here is the TextView:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"

        android:lines="2"
        android:textSize="14dp"

        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first never use dp for Text Size use  always in sp and yes font style effect on size but not to much if you use wrap_content it take the width and height as its requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to us `sp` for font sizes and `dp` for rest.

`sp` is like the `dp` unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

change your `TextView` text size like below -

```
android:textSize="14sp"
```